# How can I make sure I hit an specific server?

Tags: api, selenium, testing

I need to write some smoke test to test an application is up and running(health-check), however we have two servers and every time there is a request, it will use only one of the servers. What is the best way to make sure both servers get requested(one request per server).

P.S: The tests are written on selenium and also some REST API calls.

Comment: What are your tests supposed to check on the health check pages (i assume) ? I don't think your question has anything to do with selenium. Correct me if you think thats wrong and give me the reason.

Comment: This sounds like a question for your devs. We don't know the setup of the servers, application, etc.

Comment: Ok, the architecture is two servers server01 and server02 with a load-balancer. what I need to achieve is to run a smoke test to check the 200 response once on each server. so the question is if I was to use selenium (as a testing tool) or even make a get call to the application, what is the best way to do it to make sure both servers will receive at-least one requests.